# passing local variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

This has been asked many times, but after trying all the solutions that I can find, I'm no closer towards a solution of my own.

I have a partial, `_form` - here's the relevant part:

```
<% @tournament.sub_tournaments.each do |sub| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :sub_tournaments, sub, :validate => false do |sub_form| %>
    ...
      <table>
        ...
        <tbody>
        <%= sub_form.fields_for :standings, :validate => false do |standings| %>
          <%= render 'tournaments/form_partials/standing_fields', f: standings, sub: sub %> #here's the problem
        <% end %>  
        </tbody>
      </table>
      ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the marked line, I'm attempting to pass two variables to the given partial - `f: standings` and  `sub: sub`.  If I pass only `f: standings`, the page loads fine, but when I add `sub: sub`, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `sub'
```

which is referencing the following marked line in the `_standing_fields` partial:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= f.text_field :standing, :class => "standing", readonly: true, :type => "" %></td>
  <% if Game::TEAM_GAMES.include? sub.game.name %> #here's the problem
    <td><%= f.grouped_collection_select(:team_division_id, Team.order(:name).includes(:team_divisions), :team_divisions, :name, :id, :game_name, include_blank: true)%></td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= f.grouped_collection_select(:player_id, Player.order(:name).includes(:player), :player, :name, :id, :game_name, include_blank: true)%></td>
  <% end %>
  <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
</tr>
```

I can't think of what's going wrong, I've triple checked the syntax, spelling, commas, etc as well as restarting my redis server and the rails server as one solution suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the variables in a locals key:

```
<%= render 'tournaments/form_partials/standing_fields', locals: {f: standings, sub: sub} %>
```

Comment: that's not it - there must be something else that's triggering this because if i comment out the line in question in `_form`, i'm still getting the error.  Anyway - why `locals` key?  I've submitted more than one variable to a partial without it in other contexts and it's worked okay..?

Comment: found the error, it was a whole different wacky thing - although your answer was correct for the question i asked.  if you know about the necessity of the locals key, please let me know!